# When using the JShare API, how do I get the field values for a specific file?

Tags: java, sharepoint

I'm trying to extend the GetFile example that comes with JShare to replicate the Properties page of a document where I can see the field names and values associated with the File. The Name and Title are available fields by default, and I've added some additional ones under Site Settings -> Site Columns, though I'd be happy with just getting (and setting) Name and Title for starters.

Trying to combine the GetFile example (below) with the GetFieldValues example (really just the service.getFieldValues() call), the getFieldValues() call seems to need a list id and and item id [getFieldValues(java.lang.String listId, int itemId)], to which I have neither for a com.independentsoft.share.File. How would I get the com.independentsoft.share.List that the File is in such that I can then get its field values?

Is there a better way to go about this?  Thanks.

[Yes, I'm using my own servername, username, password.]

```
import com.independentsoft.share.File;
import com.independentsoft.share.Service;
import com.independentsoft.share.ServiceException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Service service = new Service("https://independentsoft.sharepoint.com", "username", "password");

            File file = service.getFile("/Shared Documents/Test.docx");

            System.out.println("Name: " + file.getName());
            System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
            System.out.println("MajorVersion: " + file.getMajorVersion());
            System.out.println("MinorVersion: " + file.getMinorVersion());
            System.out.println("Length: " + file.getLength());
            System.out.println("LastModifiedTime: " + file.getLastModifiedTime());
            System.out.println("CheckOutType: " + file.getCheckOutType());
            System.out.println("CheckInComment: " + file.getCheckInComment());

        } 
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getErrorString());
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getRequestUrl());

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured this out. The how is really convuluted....

```
import com.independentsoft.share.FieldValue;
import com.independentsoft.share.ListItem;
import com.independentsoft.share.Service;
import com.independentsoft.share.ServiceException;

public class Example
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Service service = new Service(...);

            com.independentsoft.share.List pse = service.getListByTitle("Documents");
            java.util.List<ListItem> items = service.getListItems(pse.getId());

            for (ListItem item : items)
            {
                java.util.List<FieldValue> values = service.getFieldValues(pse.getId(), item.getId());

                for (FieldValue value : values)
                {
                    if (value.getName().equals("FileLeafRef") && value.getValue().equals("New File.txt"))
                    {
                        for (FieldValue mine : values)
                        {
                            System.out.println(mine.getName() + ": " + mine.getValue());
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getErrorString());
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getRequestUrl());

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```